# Does increasing the weight of control points have any effect on the continuity of a B-Spline?

Tags: spline, nurbs, bspline

I have a basic question relating to NURBs Spline and tension splines like v-splines.

Does increasing the weight of a give control point or all control points have any effect on the continuity of the B-Spline ? For example in the case of a C2 continuous weighted B-Spline (NURBS) with uniform knotvector ? And also in the case of tension splines like v-Spline where tension values act similar to weights also with uniform knot vector.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Theoretically it does not decrease the continuity.  However, it practical terms there is often a change in the radius of curvature.  In the limit, when the weight is infinite, you will get parametric continuity but not geometric continuity (C but not G).

[image: A cubic NURBS curve with 5 control points. The weight on the corner control point is changed. (That escalated quickly)]

In this example, when the weight gets high enough, while if you zoom in enough you will still have a continuous curve, it's not going to be suitable for many applications that require smoothness.  So, it depends on what you're using continuity for.